# Forming a (1,1)-tensor field from a (0,2)- and (2,0)-tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> Let $A$ and $B$ be 2-tensor fields on a manifold, contravariant and covariant respectively. Prove that there exists a smooth (1,1)-tensor field $C$ with components defined by
>   $$C^i_j = A^{ik}B_{kj}$$
>   in local coordinates.

I find tensors very difficult to understand, so I could use some pointers. Here is what I have tried: if we assume that $A$ and $B$ are smooth, the component functions $A^{ik}$ and $B_{kj}$ are smooth, so it follows that the product $C^i_j$ is also smooth. Now I just define
$$C = C^i_j  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \otimes dx^j$$
and this will be a smooth tensor field since its component functions are smooth functions. But this feels a bit too simple, so I'm certain that something is wrong. Are there any other conditions on the $C^i_j$ that I have to check, besides smoothness? More generally, can I always form a tensor field just by choosing some arbitrary smooth functions and letting them be the components?

Comment: I suspect that the definition uses Einstein summation notation, so the components are not products but rather the products are summed over all $k$.

Comment: You're trying to go in a coordinate-dependent fashion, but a tensor is not a coordinate-dependent thing! You need to prove that C _is_ a tensor; that is, that it transforms appropriately under changes of coordinates.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So if I understand correctly, for a change of coordinates from $(x^i)$ to $(\tilde x^j)$, I need to show that
$$\tilde{C}^i_j = \dfrac{\partial \tilde{x}^i}{\partial x^k}\dfrac{\partial x^l}{\partial \tilde{x}^j} C^k_l$$
which should follow from the transformation laws for $A$ and $B$. Is that right?

Comment: @Andreas yes, that is the needed transformation for the components of $C$ in order that they compensate the mirrored transformations of the basis.

Comment: Formally, I agree with the statement that one has to verify independence of the choice of coordinate. However, the essence of this is that (in advaced language) that the contraction is a $GL(n,\mathbb R)$-equivariant map between the appropriate tensor spaces. In elementary terms, this is the fact that given bilenear forms on a vector space and on its dual, one can construct an endomorphism of the vector space, without using bases,